# how to use FMOD to record sound more than 5 seconds

Tags: c++, audio, wav, audio-recording, fmod

I came across FMOD recently, and i have been trying to record a sound from my c++ program using FMOD. 
I saw a nice little example given in the FMOD documentation. Its easy to understand, but only records audio for 5 seconds.

How can i use FMOD to record audio which is more than 5 seconds, could be of any custom size passed to the program?

Troubleshooting done so far-

- I think i need to do some changes to the FMOD::sound object, but I am not quite sure what.

In the example given by the FMOD,
`exinfo.length           = exinfo.defaultfrequency * 25 * exinfo.numchannels * 5;`

this is one of the parameters passed to Sound object, i tried changing it, but no effect.

- Changed the value passed to Sleep function, i reduced the value, and eventually commented that line, that had no effect on the output of the program.

I'd really appreciate any hints given on this. :)